# Symfony for PHP: inserting multiple rows to table from session using foreach

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, shopping-cart

I'm writing a function to insert a new order with order items in it. Those items are stored in session. I need to insert all the items to order items table using Symfony for PHP.

Here what I tried:

```
$cart = $session->get('cart', []);
foreach($cart as $shoesid => $sizes) {
    foreach ($sizes as $sizeid => $quantity) {
        $oishoe = $this->shoesRepository->findOneBy([
            'shoesid' => $shoesid
        ]);

        $oisize = $this->sizesRepository->findOneBy([
            'sizeid' => $sizeid
        ]);

        $oi = new Orderitems();
        $oi->setOrderid($order);
        $oi->setShoesid($oishoe);
        $oi->setQuantity($quantity);
        $oi->setSizeid($oisize);
    }
}
$manager->persist($oi);

$manager->flush();
```

But it inserts only the last item to my order items table. What code changes should I make? If you need more details, please let me know.

Comment: You create a new entry with each iteration, but you only persist once the loop has finished. What did you expect to happen? If each of those items is to be stored, persist them within the loop and only flush when the loop ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should leave `$manager->persist($oi)` in the foreach loop otherwise you only persist the last value.

Leave `$manager->flush()` outside the loop .

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for help!